# Getting an issue working with Grunt in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, grunt

I'm getting this issue after run `grunt exec:<theme>`, this shows up:

> Processed Area: frontend, Locale: en_US, Theme: Ids/prueba, File type: less.
>    [Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException]
>
> Cannot create a symlink for "/usr/local/devs/magento2/htdocs/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/source/_reset.less" and place it to "/usr/local/devs/magento2/htdocs/pub/static/frontend/Ids/prueba/en_US/css/source/_reset.less" Warning!file_get_contents(/usr/local/devs/magento2/htdocs/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---e39_INTERCEPTION): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>
> dev:source-theme:deploy [--type="..."] [--locale="..."] [--area="..."] [--theme="..."] [file1] ... [fileN]
>
> Exited with code: 1.
>   Warning: Task "exec:prueba" failed. Use --force to continue.

And after i run `grunt refresh`, shows the same after it cleans all the paths.

Now, running the command for the bin/magento `dev:source-theme:deploy` got this:

> Processed Area: frontend, Locale: en_US, Theme: Magento/luma, File type: less.
>
> [Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException]
>
> Cannot create a symlink for "/usr/local/devs/magento2/htdocs/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/source/_reset.less" and place it to "/usr/local/devs/mage
>     nto2/htdocs/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/source/_reset.less"
>
> dev:source-theme:deploy [--type="..."] [--locale="..."] [--area="..."] [--theme="..."] [file1] ... [fileN]

I was triyng to fix this by following a lot of instructions on other issues already, nothing worked.

Any ideas why this might be happening?
I have a VM configured running of Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS , and have node 5.4.1 with npm 3.3.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked for a bounty, but these seems to be fixed after re run chmod 777 to pub.

Its very hard to develop in magento 2.

Edit:

Open up `app/etc/di.xml` and find the `virtualType name="developerMaterialization"` section. In that section you'll find an item `name="view_preprocessed"` that needs to be modified or deleted. You can modify it by changing the contents from         `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink to Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

Delete the files under `pub/static` to get rid of any existing symlinks. You may want to be careful not to delete the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Then I suggest you accept your answer. Although having all your files in a 777 mode isn't advisable. There might be another issue.

Comment: I cannot accep answer since I am not asker.

Comment: 777 is temporary.

Comment: @ezequiel-alba did this worked? Can you confirm?

Comment: @Flakerim a little late, but yeah at that moment that works!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps

Execute the following command in your terminal, adapt Placeholders accordingly:

`VBoxManage setextradata YOURVMNAME VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/YOURSHAREFOLDERNAME 1`

And verify it by the command
`VBoxManage getextradata YOURVMNAME enumerate`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with grunt throwing up this error when running `grunt exec: <theme>` and I realised that I didn't run my command prompt in administrator mode.

Hopefully this might help someone - obviously it might not be the contributing factor, but you never know!